# Input field blocked if Submit button pressed to check validation form

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, es6-class

I try to code the following :

1. The user enters his name and first name in a form.
2. When he click on the Submit button, the form validates the values
3. A modal is opened after the submit button is clicked

But I meet this issue :

If the user leaves a field Empty, and then click on the Submit button, he can't type anything in the fields. The form is blocked, he can't do anything.

Here is the Javascript piece of code :

```
validateForm = () => {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(this.needsvalidation, form => {
      this.send.addEventListener('click', event => {
        if(form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
}
```

You can see the page here :
http://p4547.phpnet.org/velos/form.html

Please note : I used the "click" event instead of the Submit event, because I don't send any data to anywhere. I only launch a modal bootstrap when I click on the Book button.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding `event.preventDefault()` regardless of if `form.checkValidity()` is false.

Comment: @JossClassey You mean adding again  event.preventDefault(); just before form.classList.add('was-validated');  ?

Comment: Yes, just to see what it does :)

Comment: @JossClassey It does'nt work. I also tried to put the event.preventDefault(); before the If as well, but nothing changes. Result is the same.

Comment: Okay, that rules out one thing! It would be good if you could put your code in https://codesandbox.io/ so that we can play around with it.

Comment: I checked the link provided and it seems you show up an overlay element that has `opacity: 0` applied (so it can'tn be seen)  that covers the page thus you can't interact with the form as it is under that overlay.

Comment: Where is `validateForm()` called from? It doesn't seem to be validating anything. It appears to be binding some code to `window.load` event, which might already have happened.

Comment: @ths where do you see the overlay ?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu the validateForm() is called at the bottom of the JS file.

Comment: on the site you provided.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue :

In my Javascript code, I had this line :
            this.modal.style.display = "block";

the block display was preventing the possibility to fill the fields when the Submit button was already clicked.